# How to add an event image in the background of an in event in a particular day?

Tags: fullcalendar

Hey y'all, I raised the question since I'm really having a hard-time dealing with it..

What I would like is for the calendar to somehow look like this: http://www.juice.ph/events#1298822400

Any tips (or I guess code snippets for that matter) on how could I achieve this? Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used background images to decorate my event slot (in *agendaDay* view).

```
.fc-event {
   background: url('tick.png') no-repeat;
   min-height: 49px;
   min-width: 64px;
}
```

In month view, Fullcalendar set for you an identifier to each cell :

- **.fc-day1** ...**.fc-dayN** or
- **.fc-week0 .fc-sun**...**N**

You can set CSS style for each desired cell, or set-it via jquery in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use image instead of CSS class you can use the following approach:
1. Specify image url in extended props of the [event objects](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object):

```
    events: [
    {
      title: 'test 1', 
      start: '2020-02-06',
      extendedProps:{
          img:'https://pinngle.me/img/logo.png'
      }         
    },
    {
      title: 'test 2', 
      start: '2020-02-06',
      extendedProps:{
          img:'https://pinngle.me/img/logo.png'
      }         
    }
  ]
```

2. Add [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) function that will create image and prepend it to the event object:

   ```
   eventRender: function(info) {
       let img = document.createElement('img');
       img.src = info.event.extendedProps.img;
       info.el.prepend(img);
   }
   ```